# Which users have answered which surveys

Tags: php, limesurvey

When building an extension for LimeSurvey I have created a separate UserAccount functionality outside of LM original package. However I would like that when a user submits answers for a survey the user ID and the survey ID to be stored. I am having trouble understanding where to do this. The Answers Model part of saving looks like this:

```
function insertRecords($data)
{
    $ans = new self;
    foreach ($data as $k => $v)
        $ans->$k = $v;
    try
    {
        return $ans->save();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am wondering how to go with this, I can retrieve user ID and Survey ID so that is not a problem, I just don't know which part of code is responsible for saving the survey.
Any hints would be appreciated,
-D

Comment: what is `save()`? its probably `catch` though.

Comment: save() saves the data straight into the table because the model belongs to that table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar, and I'm using a combination of the [Remote Control API](http://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API) and additional [attribute fields](http://manual.limesurvey.org/Tokens#User-defined_attribute_fields).

I use attribute fields to track user id (among other things) between token and survey tables by creating hidden questions with default "answers" of attributes, and then use the remote control api to manipulate them.

So basically the functionality already exists for you to do this, you shouldn't have to rewrite or add anything!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using limesurvey 2. In that case survey responses are saved in

```
limesurvey/application/helpers/expresssions/em_manager_helper.php -> 
_UpdateValuesInDatabase() .
```

Comment: Answers model is to save answer options of a question. It is not related to saving survey responses. Survey responses are saved in lime_survey_<sid> table.